# Logarithms of Negative Numbers

Tags: logarithms

In Algebra II, I learned that you cannot take the logarithm of a negative number. However, when visiting the topic again, I realized that the identity $e^{i \theta} = \cos{\theta} + i\sin{\theta}$ gives a way to solve for this.

Given the problem 
$\log_2 {x} + \log_2 (x+2) = 3.$ The given solution excluded -4 as extraneous. I plugged it in, getting
$$\log_2 {8} + 2(\log_2 (-1)) = 3,$$
which resolves into 
$$2(\log_2 (-1)) = 0,$$
$$\frac{2(\log (-1)}{\log (2)} = 0.$$
I then used $e^{i\pi} = -1$, which follows that $\log (-1) = \frac{i\pi}{\ln (10)}$. When plugging back in the value of $\log (-1)$, I saw that everything had a real value except $i$, which then means $i = 0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I formatted something wrong or if you need clarification, please let me know.

Comment: "Given the problem log2 (x) + log2 (x+2) = 3. The given solution excluded -4 as extraneous. I plugged it in, getting log2 (8) + 2[log2 (-1)] = 3" I'm not sure what you did here.

Comment: @AdamJamil you could use LaTeX to clean up the math quite a bit. For example, instead of  "e^(i * theta) = cos(theta) + isin(theta)" try "e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)" . Wrap that expression in "$\$$" symbols (one or two one each side) to get $$e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: How do you go from $\log_2(-4)+\log_2(-4+2)=3$ to $\log_2(8)+2\log_2(-1)=3$?

Comment: In addition to the questions about the $8$ and $-1$, I'll point something else out. Sometimes the formula $\log AB = \log A + \log B$ works for complex numbers, and sometimes it doesn't. The two sides always differ by a multiple of $2\pi i$, however this multiple need not be zero. The only way to avoid this problem would be to in some sense make $\log$ a "multivalued function." It would be somewhat similar to declaring that $\sqrt{4}$ can be both $2$ and $-2$.

Comment: $\log z=\log|z|+i\text {Arg} z $ if you take the principal branch. Exponentiating both sides gives $ z=|z|e^{i\text{Arg}( z)} $ as you might hope to expect.

Comment: @user208259 I took out the two negative ones from the logs, making them their own quantity to make sure I was using complex quantities. The 2 and 4 became eight.

Comment: @AdamJamil I can't follow that. Could you edit the question with the detailed calculations? Everybody is asking the same question, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

In the complex numbers, you can take the logarithm of negative numbers as you are thinking.  Unfortunately, the answer is not unique because of the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$.  From $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$ you also get $e^{i(\theta+2\pi)}=\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$, so you can add any integral multiple of $2\pi i$ to the log and get another value. You can restrict the values of the integer part of the log function to an interval of length $2 \pi i$ (say to $[-\pi i,\pi i)$ )to make it single valued, similar to what we do with $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$